# SED replace a word inside a bracket

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, centos

I need to change some words in bulk, but because of the brackets inside it, I think I do something wrong.

#### Line that needs to be changed

```
echo "CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/admin/index.html";
```

I need to change it to this:

```
echo "CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/reseller/index.html";
```

I tried it with:    `sed -ie 's/admin/reseller/' *`

But does not change anything, I hope someone knows the right command for it.

Comment: Why the `[` ?  .

Comment: @Paolo thanks was a typo

Comment: Why not `sed -i 's/admin/reseller/' file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo '"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/admin/index.html";' | sed 's/\/admin\//\/reseller\//g'
"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/reseller/index.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

your input has slash and you are using slash as sed seperator
Either escape the slashes in input by preceeding them with backslash:

```
echo '"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/admin/index.html";' | sed 's/\/admin\//\/reseller\//g'
"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/reseller/index.html";
```

OR change seperator to any other like pipe:

```
echo '"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/admin/index.html";' | sed 's|admin|reseller|g'
"CMD_PLUGINS_ADMIN/reseller/index.html";
```